# soundblast live on linx mint: fatal: module snd-emu10k1 not found

Tags: linux-mint, audio, alsa

I'm trying to get my soundblast live 5.1 emu10k1 (rev 7) working.
It is listed in my xconf settings but the onboard sound processor is the standard (i have tried to make de soundblaster standard, but then I had no sound).

I ran `alsamixer` from a terminal and there's my soundblaster live 5.1 shown as the first device, but I cannot get any sound out of it...

#### screenshot from alsamixer

[image: ss #1]

*original URL: https://db.tt/ukN6Qd2T*

I found a tutorial from Ubuntu which tells step by step what to do.
When I'm at the point of doing a `modprobe`, this is the output in terminal:

```
FATAL: Module snd_EMU10K1 not found.
```

What can I do to make my soundblaster live working?

Comment: How did you try to make the SB standard?

Comment: By editing the line in xconf settimfs editor > and then looking for xfce4mixer. I have no audio settings or whatsoever in my menu under 'system' or 'settings'. Edit: because of the error, it seems like I am missing the emu10k1 module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To select the default sound card, use `pavucontrol` (Pulse Audio Volume Control).

(`modprobe` is case sensitive; the module is called `snd-emu10k1`, not `snd-EMU10K1`.)

Comment: I have sound now from 1 outputconnector on my sb live. The other not, that is a different question I guess.